# Symfony - Api-Platform framework: Get all items of a user

Tags: rest, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm a young developer and I recently discover [Api-Platform](https://api-platform.com) to make a full rest api.

Currently, I'm following the [doc](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/api-bundle/), but I don't understand how to get all books of a person by example.

Here I am:

I have Book and Person entities auto generated, I just add a ManyToMany relation between them.

Then I have the following results:

GET `api.platform.dev/app_dev.php/`

```
{
    @context: "/app_dev.php/contexts/Entrypoint",
    @id: "/app_dev.php/",
    @type: "Entrypoint",
    person: "/app_dev.php/people",
    book: "/app_dev.php/books"
}
```

GET `api.platform.dev/app_dev.php/people/3`

```
{
    @context: "/app_dev.php/contexts/Person",
    @id: "/app_dev.php/people/3",
    @type: "http://schema.org/Person",
    birthDate: null,
    description: "test",
    gender: "Femme",
    name: "test",
    url: null,
    books: [
        "/app_dev.php/books/1",
        "/app_dev.php/books/4"
    ]
}
```

Here is my questions, How can I get in the second result an hypermedia to all books of the person, and What is the best option to get all books of a person ?

I have started with create my custom operation:

```
#services.yml
resource.person.item_operation.custom_get:
    class:   "Dunglas\ApiBundle\Api\Operation\Operation"
    public:  false
    factory:
        - "@api.operation_factory"
        - "createItemOperation"
    arguments:
        - "@resource.person"                  # Resource
        - ["GET"]                             # Methods
        - "/people/{id}/books"                # Path
        - "AppBundle:Person:custom"           # Controller
        - "my_custom_route2"                  # Route name
        - # Context (will be present in Hydra documentation)
            "@type":       "hydra:Operation"
            "hydra:title": "A custom operation"
            "returns":     "xmls:string"
```

and

```
// PersonController.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Controller\ResourceController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PersonController extends ResourceController
{
    public function customAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return parent::getAction($request, $id);
    }
}
```

result on GET `api.platform.dev/app_dev.php/people/3/books` is the same of the basic `api.platform.dev/app_dev.php/people/3`, normal I call the parent.

But now what is the best way to have something like this:

```
# GET api.platform.dev/app_dev.php/people/3/books
{
    @context: "/app_dev.php/contexts/Book",
    @id: "/app_dev.php/people/3/books",
    @type: "hydra:PagedCollection",
    hydra:totalItems: 2,
    hydra:itemsPerPage: 30,
    hydra:firstPage: "/app_dev.php/people/3/books",
    hydra:lastPage: "/app_dev.php/people/3/books",
    hydra:member: [
        {
            @id: "/app_dev.php/books/1",
            @type: "http://schema.org/Book",
            illustrator: [ ],
            isbn: null,
            numberOfPages: 1230,
            author: [ ],
            datePublished: null,
            description: "Desription",
            genre: null,
            name: "someone",
            publisher: null
        },
        {
            @id: "/app_dev.php/books/2",
            @type: "http://schema.org/Book",
            illustrator: [ ],
            isbn: null,
            numberOfPages: 1230,
            author: [ ],
            datePublished: null,
            description: "Desription",
            genre: null,
            name: "someone",
            publisher: null
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I get `api.platform.dev/app_dev.php/people/3` add this IRI `/app_dev.php/people/3/books`

Thanks you for the help you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating sub collections like this is doable but complex with the v1 of API Platform as it requires to create a lot of custom classes (it will be easier with the v2).

What I would suggest is to use the following structure:

`GET /books?people=/people/3`: retrieve all books owned bu the people 3

It can be done easily using [the builtin API Platform search filter](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/api-bundle/filters#search-filter).

Then, if you want hypermedia support (btw do you really need it - I mean, is your client able to dereference such hypermedia links?), you need can [create a custom Symfony normalizer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/serializer.html#adding-normalizers-and-encoders) decorating the `Dunglas\ApiBundle\JsonLd\Serializer\ItemNormalizer` (service `api.json_ld.normalizer.item`) provided by API Platform and adding a link to `/books?people=/people/3` for the `books` property.

If you want to still want to follow the road you started, you need to use the `Dunglas\ApiBundle\Hydra\Serializer\CollectionNormalizer` to normalize your collection in the Hydra format. You can still decorate the ItemNormalizer to point to your custom collection URL.

I hope this help.